# Get number of partitions for a topic before creating a direct stream using kafka and spark streaming?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have the following code that creates a direct stream using kafka connector for spark.

```
public abstract class MessageConsumer<T> 
{
    public JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, T>> createConsumer(final JavaStreamingContext jsc, 
        final Collection<String> topics, final String servers)
    {
        return KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jsc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, T>Subscribe(topics,
                ConsumerUtils.getKafkaParams(servers, getGroupId(), getDeserializerClassName())));
    }

    protected abstract String getDeserializerClassName();

    protected abstract String getGroupId();
}
```

This works fine, but now I want to change the logic so the consumer will consume from a specific partition of a topic, as opposed to letting Kafka decide which partition to consume from. I do this by using the same algorithm that the default kafka partitioner uses to determine what partition to send the message to based on the key `DefaultPartitioner.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;`. I then simply assign my consumer to this partition. In order for this to work, I need to know the total number of partitions available for the topic. However I do not know how to get this information using the kafka/spark streaming API.

I have been able to get this to work with other parts of my application that don't use Spark, but I am unclear of how to achieve this when using Spark. The only way I can see to achieving this is by creating another consumer before creating the direct stream, and using it to get the total number of partitions, and then closing this consumer. See the below code for this implementation:

```
public abstract class MessageConsumer<T> 
{
    public JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, T>> createConsumer(final JavaStreamingContext jsc, 
        final String topic, final String servers, final String groundStation)
    {
        final Properties props = ConsumerUtils.getKafkaParams(servers, getGroupId(), getDeserializerClassName());
        final Consumer<String, T> tempConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        final int numPartitions = tempConsumer.partitionsFor(topic).size();
        final int partition = calculateKafkaPartition(groundStation.getBytes(), numPartitions);
        final TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, partition);
        tempConsumer.close();

        return KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jsc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, T>Assign(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition),
                ConsumerUtils.getKafkaParams(servers, getGroupId(), getDeserializerClassName())));
    }

    protected abstract String getDeserializerClassName();

    protected abstract String getGroupId();

    private static int calculateKafkaPartition(final byte[] keyBytes, final int numberOfPartitions)
    {
        return Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numberOfPartitions;
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem right to me at all, surely there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Direct stream is deprecated as of Spark 2.4, by the way

Comment: I did not know this, thank you! Do you know what is the recommended way to create a stream now? The documentation here :https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html still refers to direct stream...?

Comment: Structrued Streaming - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use Kafka's AdminClient to describe the topic. There's no Spark API for such information

Comment: Does the topic already have to exist before using this approach? I'm using Confluent's docker kafka image, which allows the topics to be created on the fly by the producers/consumers, instead of pre-definng them.When I use the approach you've suggested, I get an `This server does not host this topic-partition` error when calling the `describeTopics` method

Comment: 1) It is recommended to set `auto.create.topics=false` 2) You do need to create a topic before describing it, yes. 3) You can also use `AdminClient.createTopic`

Comment: Yes we had previously been using a different image that allowed us to create topics via our docker-compose file, but the confluent version does not let us do this, and we want the flexibility of not having to predefine our topics and being able to create them on the fly. But if it is advised against I will look into other ways we can achieve this

Comment: The wurstmeister one is the only one I know that does. You don't have to use the cp-kafka image.

Comment: Yes I believe that's the one we were previously using, although I believe there was a reason why we had to change images, I just can't remember. I'll be sure to keep that in mind for the future though.